# Difference between svg path and an image.svg

Tags: html, image, svg

I would like to know more about svg and I have a question.

For exemple, I've export a shape with Illustrator as html code so I have this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 1920 600" enable-background="new 0 0 1920 600" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <polygon fill="none" stroke="#B24539" points="0,297 0,379.3 26.9,346.1  "/>
</g>
```

And I want to know the difference between using svg with code like this and using an image.svg ?

Comment: Thats not exported as html, its exported as svg.

Comment: @taxicala But is there a big difference between these 2 ways of use ?

Answer (score 0):

Inline SVG would allow you to target parts of your SVG with CSS:

```
.svg {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

This is not possible if the SVG was brought in with an `<img>` tag.

Here's a post from CSS Tricks that talks about the many different ways you can use SVGs: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use inline svg as @restlessbit points out, because you have more control over the style.

For example, changing background colors, adding path colors and even adding text to an SVG can be done when adding SVG inline.

Here is a post that illustrates some of these mentioned benefits to using inline SVG in case you wanted some more info: https://viget.com/extend/getting-started-with-inline-svg

Comment: It would be best if you summarised what's said in the link in your own words. If the link rots your answer will be much less useful currently.